# Resposive font in websites

Tags: css, fonts, responsive-design

I want to make font responsive to browse width change, I make like this

```
<div>
   <h1>hello world  </h1>
</div>

div{
width:50px%;
min-heigth:300px;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:120%;
}
h1{ 
    font-size:6em;
}
```

here's an exmple on 
http://jsfiddle.net/wZmAc/

The font doesn't respond! Can somebody help!

Comment: Uh, what do you want the font to respond to? There's nothing "responsive" here. There are also several typos in your CSS code.

Comment: @ BoltClock, I want it to respond to windows re-size, What do you mean of your comment, I can't understand :S

Comment: note: width:50px%;   choose or px or %;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to scale the font to fit the screen and you're willing to consider a Javascript solution, you might check out [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/) (jQuery) or the [InflateText.js](http://rjzaworski.com/projects/inflateText/) remix.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
body {
    font: normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;        /* 24px / 16px = 1.5em */
}
```

Recomendend reading:

1. [responsive design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)
2. [fluid grids](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/) (to see what 24px and 16px mean)